The transparent part in android TextView png background occlude the other view
I has an png image file, and except its center has a object, all around are transparent.
But when I use it as a TextView background, the transparent part in this png occlude other TextView with white color.
android:background="@drawable/my_png_file"

How can it not occlude? Thank you very much!
